# How to match one per line in a regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm having a problem with a regex I created.
My company searches for errors in an error file and tries to match the file to a set of possible strings.
If one of the strings is found, then it means that that specific error has occurred, and then we send an e-mail for the client telling them what errors have occurred and with a count for each specific set of strings.

So let's say I have the `string`:

```
Number 123456789: Duplicate transaction detected
Number 543267890: is a duplicate for this vendor
Password error number 987654321
The total can not be negative
```

Then I would search for all the "Duplicate" errors, the "Password" errors and the "Negative" errors.
Each type of error has a set of strings that might indicate that.

I'm running the following regex to get the Duplicate errors:

```
number_of_errors = re.subn(
    r"(is a duplicate for this vendor|Duplicate transaction detected)", "", string,
)[1]
```

The `number_of_errors` variable holds the amount of times the regex was found in the string.
It was working fine until the third-party software that does the error handling started to create the file differently.

Right now the file might look like:

```
Number 123456789: Duplicate transaction detected because it is a duplicate for this vendor
Number 543267890: is a duplicate for this vendor
Password error number 987654321
The total can not be negative
```

As you can see, right now the first line would be counted twice, because the regex matches both strings in the first line.

Is there any way to match only **once per line** in the regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know one possible adjustment would be to split the whole file by new lines and then regex each line specifically, and just add +1 to the variable if found something in the line.

But I'm guessing that would be way slower than modifying the previous regex to just match once per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use

```
r"(?m)^.*?(is a duplicate for this vendor|Duplicate transaction detected)"
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xFg3Pv/1). The `(?m)^.*?` part makes the pattern match at the start of each line since the caret matches the line start position and the `.*?` matches any zero or more characters other than linebreaks, but as few as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter count within the `re.subn` function. This is to indicate the maximum number of replacements to be done.

```
number_of_errors = re.subn(
    r"(is a duplicate for this vendor|Duplicate transaction detected)", "", string, count = 1)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I want. With your answer it just stops at count = 1, even though there are more matches in other lines. For the specific example I posted last, it should return 2, because there are 2 lines with matches for that regex.

Comment: @felipetnh it seems you are confusing two statements. You clearly stated that you wanted the first line to be counted only once and not twice, now you are sayiing it should be counted twice. Which is which??

Comment: I think I might have explained it wrong then.
I want the regex to look at the whole string (which in my case might have hundreds of lines) and match only once per line and return the total amount.

Comment: @felipetnh in that case you need to write a new regex pattern to distinguish the two lines. eg include `:` when writng the first part etc

Answer (score 0):

If you check the parameters of `re.subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` you see that there is a parameter count, which you can set to 1.